# SonarQube TFS 2015 express Integration

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfs-2015

I follow [SonarQube documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services):

But with TFS2015 express I don't see build step "SonarQube for MSBuild". Is that some plugin to install into TFS express ? Or the feature is not allowed to Express edition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This build step is RTM with TFS 2015 update1.  Details please refer [Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update1-vs)

> SonarQube build tasks that embed the sonar-msbuild-runner 1.0 work
> with on-premises and hosted agents. You can now use two build tasks to
> execute a SonarQube analysis in conjunction with MSBuild. Before the
> build steps that execute the actual MSBuild, insert a SonarQube for
> MSBuild - Begin Analysis task to specify the SonarQube project
> parameters, the connection to the SonarQube server, and (until
> SonarQube 5.2 is available) the connection to the SonarQube database.
> After the build and any test tasks, append a SonarQube for MSBuild -
> End Analysis task to complete the analysis and send the data to
> SonarQube.

So, the feature is also not in TFS Express 2015. There is no TFS Express 2015 upade1 for now. If you want to use this feature, you may have to use either **TFS2015 update1** or **VS Team Service**.